# Remove filtering from all sheets before run macros

Tags: vba, excel

I want to put a small code before every macro I have that removes any filter from all the sheets of my workbook.

What I have done is the following but it seems not to be working properly. When I click on the button it does not remove the filters but if I run it line by line it does.

I don"t understand.

```
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

' Begin the loop to disable all filters
For i = 1 To WS_Count
    If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `for loop` isn't being used as you aren't referencing `i`. Also, the second criteria of your `If` statement basically makes the first criteria irrelevant, try this:

```
WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

' Begin the loop to disable all filters
For i = 1 To WS_Count
    If Thisworkbook.Sheets(i).FilterMode Then
        Thisworkbook.Sheets(i).ShowAllData
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

*To remove filters example would be*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet

    For Each Sht In Worksheets
        If Sht.AutoFilterMode = True Then
            Debug.Print Sht.Name
            Sht.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

***[Worksheet.AutoFilterMode Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821903.aspx)***